# Can just adding an apostrophe to input lead to SQLi that makes changes in the database?

Tags: web-application, sql-injection

If I try to find a SQL injection vulnerability in an admin login form by putting an apostrophe after the username (`username'`) and write a password, will this vulnerability checking effect or modify anything in the database?

When I put an apostrophe after the username there was no SQL syntax error, rather the site reloaded.

Comment: please do not capitalise every word

Comment: what the effects will be are up to how the site is coded - login attempts are most certainly logged

Comment: But i had just put an apostrophe,nothing else!that was a login page,still chance of any modifying in the database?

Answer (score 1):

It's very, very unlikely that it would change anything.

I think it's safe to assume that the SQL query you are injecting into is a SELECT query. Such a query does not change the content of the database, it just fetches data. If you terminated the query (e.g. with `;`) and started a new INSERT or UPDATE query you could possibly change data, but it doesn't sound like you did that.

If you get no error and the site just reloads, that is probably a sign that your injection attack was detected and averted. Or that it just didn't work.

So while I don't think the SQL query you injected into changed anything, it's impossible to say anything with 100% certainty. The application could follow any arbitrary logic, and without reviewing the source code you can't really know. But let me say this: If I were you, I wouldn't be that worried about it.

Comment: I just put apostrophe after the username,didnt do anything after that.Only put apostrophe and the site reloaded.is there any chance of modifying of anything?

Comment: @Rifat No, that couldnt possibly have produced a query that made changes.

Comment: would have been highly glad if you assure me fully :(

Comment: That would be impossible to assure you fully.

Comment: @Rifat See my edit for some expanded thoughts on it.

Comment: Oh bro,then let me ask you another questions.if i put apostrophe after username to check vulnerability,Does this Effect another page in the same site?For example,there was Online admission with 145.167.89.124 something like that server,is there any chance of modifying of that server Documents?

Comment: @Rifat - Before you play around with SQL-injections you should understand what you are doing, and certainly you should learn this on your own computer, not a public site! You cannot delegate responsibility to anyone but yourself.

Comment: @martinstoeckli sry bro but i found on internet that putting apostrophe after username only checks vulnerability doesn't change anything,thats why i dared to do that :(

Comment: @Rifat - Every sane system can handle apostrophes, after all this can be a valid part of a name. But as others wrote, it entirely depends on the implementation of the target system.

Comment: @martinstoeckli The site just reloaded,and didnt react o my input.I didnt use any commands,or, --, etc etc..so confused what are you guys saying :(

Comment: Just used an apostrophe after username randomly to check if there was any sql syntax error..